# Can't import large dictionary to firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I have a dictionary with 200+ elements, when I try to use requests.put to upload the whole dictionary to firebase, it can successfully run in python but didn't show up on firebase.
This is the code I used:
`requests.put(url= "https://test-*****.firebaseio.com/world/countrylanguage/.json", json = language_dict)`

However, I tried to import partial dictionary with only a few elements by using the same code, it works and shows up on firebase:

```
 {"CountryCode":"ABW", "Language":"English", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":9.5},
 {"CountryCode":"ABW", "Language":"Papiamento", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":76.7},
 {"CountryCode":"ABW", "Language":"Spanish", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":7.4},
 {"CountryCode":"AFG", "Language":"Balochi", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":0.9},
 {"CountryCode":"AFG", "Language":"Dari", "IsOfficial":"T", "Percentage":32.1},
 {"CountryCode":"AFG", "Language":"Pashto", "IsOfficial":"T", "Percentage":52.4},
 {"CountryCode":"AFG", "Language":"Turkmenian", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":1.9},
 {"CountryCode":"AFG", "Language":"Uzbek", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":8.8},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Ambo", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":2.4},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Chokwe", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":4.2},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Kongo", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":13.2},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Luchazi", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":2.4},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Luimbe-nganguela", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":5.4},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Luvale", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":3.6},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Mbundu", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":21.6},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Nyaneka-nkhumbi", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":5.4},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Ovimbundu", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":37.2}]

countrylanguage1 = {}
for i in countrylanguage:
    key = i['CountryCode']
    key2 = i['Language']
    value_dict = {key: val for key,val in i.items() if key != 'CountryCode'}
    value_dict = {key: val for key, val in value_dict.items() if key != 'Language'}
    countrylanguage1.setdefault(key,{})[key2] = value_dict

requests.put(url="https://********.firebaseio.com/world/countrylanguage/.json", json = countrylanguage1)
```

[image: This is my firebase with partial dictionary imported]

Which means the code is correct. So I'm confused why I can't import the whole dictionary. Is there a size limit to upload to firebase? And if so, how can I upload the whole dictionary to my firebase? I'm not allowed to use firebase library.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what didn't work the way you expect.  If the API you're using failed and generated an error, you should show what that is.

Comment: @Doug It successfully run and doesn't show any errors in python, but just doesn't show up in firebase...

Comment: What are you doing to check for errors on the API call?  I see nothing.

Comment: @Doug Sorry I'm new to firebase and I have no idea what is API call?  but when I run the requests.put() code in pycharm, it didn't show any error and 'Process finished with exit code 0'

Comment: You should check the results of the API call you make with `requests.put()`. It is not guaranteed to succeed.